# php update the dates in every column of mysql table so that they auto increment by one day

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, increment

I have a mysql table called Posts with a datetime field called post_date

Here is a screenshot of the database table:

[image]

I want to set the post_date for the first row to today’s date, then add one day to each of the post_dates after that until they are all updated - so if today is Sep 22 2017 and there are 5 rows, post_date fields would be:

```
2017-09-22 12:00:00
2017-09-23 12:00:00
2017-09-24 12:00:00
2017-09-25 12:00:00
2017-09-26 12:00:00
```

And if there are 50 rows, it would advance 50 days, etc.

My latest approach is to get the total number of rows using mysqli_num_rows() and then store that value in a variable.

Then I tried using `date()` and `mktime()` to create a “start date” and “end date”, then a foreach loop to update the dates in this range.

But this is not working. Here is the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//begin if statement to get row count
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Posts")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

//end if statement to get row count

// create foreach loop with a date range equal to the number of rows, and update the post_date values by one day as many times as there are rows in the table

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $begin = new DateTime($today);
    list($y,$m,$d)=explode('-',$today);
    $day_last = Date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d+$row_cnt,$y));
    $end = new DateTime($day_last);

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

    foreach($daterange as $date) {

        $sql_date_update = "UPDATE Posts SET post_date = $date->format("Y-m-d h:i:s")";

        if ($conn->query($sql_date_update) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully"."<br>";
                } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }    
    }
```

I have tried so many different approaches and nothing is working. Any tips would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use SQL variables in combination with DATE_ADD()

```
SET @startDate = NOW();
SET @days = -1;
UPDATE Posts SET post_date = DATE_ADD(@startDate, INTERVAL (@days := @days + 1) day)
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael M. This is behaving strangely for me. I ran this once and it worked. But after that, it is returning the following error: # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).  I tried then tried deleting all the rows and creating new ones, but still returning the same result.

Comment: i have edited my answer cause it wasn't exactly what you wanted to archieve

Comment: thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a generated column here:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_date DATETIME AS DATE_ADD('2017-09-22', INTERVAL id DAY);
);
```

This approach requires MySQL `5.7.6` or higher.  It directly couples a regular auto increment column with a date counter.  I think it only makes sense to base the generated date on a fixed initial date.  This matches the behavior of the auto increment column which is zero based.

Comment: thank you for sharing, this is a bummer for me as the mysql version on my server is 5.5.51-38.2 - thank you for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Is this you looking for ?

```
    $startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $getPostIdArray = array(12,13,14,15,17,16,21); // this should be select query with the needed post ids
    sort($getPostIdArray);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($getPostIdArray) ;  $i++){
        $startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.$i.' day', strtotime($startDate)));
        echo '<pre> Next Date ' . $startDate;
        //UPDATE SET  post_date = ".'".$startDate."`." WHERE id = $getPostIdArray[0]
    }
```